# How to cross-compile source code for MIPS without delay-slot implemented

Tags: mips, cross-compiling

I am now trying to cross-compile my C code for MIPS architecture. 
And I am using a cross-compiler I make on my host computer. I have a FPGA board which implemented with a multi-cycle (not pipeline) MIPS core. I was just wondering if I could compile the code without delay-slot yet keep other optimizations made via GCC.
The simplest flag -O for optimization still implements the delay-slot. So I was wondering if there is any options to simply disable delay-slot in MIPS cross-compiling.

Comment: Have you tried passing `-fno-delayed-branch -Wa,-O0` as options to gcc?

Comment: @Michael I have tried both `-fno-delayed-branch -Wall` and `-O0`, yet they did not work.

Comment: Did you use `-O0`, or `-Wa,-O0` as I suggested in my previous comment? `-Wa,-O0` is an option that will be passed on to the assembler.

Comment: Yes, I tried '-O0' and '-Wa,-O0', both of them did not work.

Comment: Actually, I did not compile the cross-compiler myself, instead I use the SDK provided by [Imaginaion](http://www.imgtec.com/tools/mips-tools/), precisely, the **Linux GNU Toolchain**.